# Import all Sheets of an Excel in a folder, without mentioning Excel Name

Tags: r

I need to import all sheets with their respective names with mentioning only folder path.

```
filename <-"D:/Dash/"
sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(filename)
 SheetList <- lapply(sheets,openxlsx::read.xlsx,xlsxFile=filename)
 names(SheetList) <- sheets
```

But it shows error as the file name is not mentioned.

**What I need is**
Importing those sheets from Excel in the folder with only folder path mentioned.

Comment: you want `list.files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @MichaelChirico, you can do that using `list.files`

```
path <- "D:/Dash/"
excelFiles <- list.files(path = path, pattern = '.*\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE) # or xls, xlsm, xlsb, etc.
```

Now extracting the data

**method 1**

```
sheetNamesList <- lapply(seq_along(excelFiles), 
                         function (k) c(file = excelFiles[k], 
                                        sheet = openxlsx::getSheetNames(excelFiles[k]))
                         )
sheetData <- lapply(seq_along(sheetNamesList), 
                    function (k) openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = sheetNamesList[[k]]['file'], 
                                                     sheet = sheetNamesList[[k]]['sheet'])
                    )
```

**method 2**

```
sheetData <- lapply( seq_along(excelFiles), 
                     function (k) {
                       tmpSheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(excelFiles[k])
                       tmpData <- lapply(seq_along(tmpSheets), function (n) openxlsx::read.xlsx(excelFiles[k], sheet = tmpSheets[n]))
                       tmpData
                     })
```

Comment: sheetData execution shows:-

 ""Error in read.xlsx.default(xlsxFile = sheetNamesList[[k]]["file"], sheet = sheetNamesList[[k]]["sheet"]) : 
  Cannot find sheet named "NA" ""

Comment: how do I further use separate workbooks to perform functions on?

Comment: "sheetData" creates a list and not a list of the list!